# Passing the parameter correctly and MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql

I don't see why I'm not properly passing the userId to the query string here. Here is the result I get from SQL query:

> array(2) { ["@attributes"]=> array(1) { ["type"]=> string(7) "integer"
>   } [0]=> string(3) "939" } 
> string(86) "UPDATE wp_users SET user_id
>   = "Array" WHERE user_email = "user.mail.com""

This is my code:

```
    $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
    $email = $_SESSION['user_email'];


    var_dump($user_id);
    // Attempt insert query execution
    $sql = 'UPDATE wp_users SET user_id = "'.$user_id.'" WHERE user_email = "'.$email.'"';
    var_dump($sql);die;
```

I want the result to be 939 as user_Id in SQL query, not array value.

Thank you all for your prompt reply.

Comment: You never execute the query. I don't really understand what you are trying to ask

Comment: @B001ᛦ not getting the correct values in query, that's the problem, how do I get the value of user_id=939 instead of user_id = "Array"

Comment: Looks like you are storing more than just the user id in `$_SESSION['user_id']`, looks like you need to use `$user_id[0]` in this case.

Comment: @NigelRen yes that's it, thank you

Comment: I suggest you read about prepared statements. The *PHP: The Right Way* site has [databases](https://phptherightway.com/#databases) chapter that can be a starting point.